# Is there a way to use 'Show Call Hierarchy' on useState setters in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-hooks

The feature seems to work for most regular functions, and even the components themselves when using functional components, but nothing is returned for the `useState` provided setter functions.

Example

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type Props = {}

const Example: React.FC<Props> = (props: Props) => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState<number>(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        wrapperFunction();
    });

    const wrapperFunction = () => {
        changeValue();
    }

    const changeValue = () => {
        setValue(7);
    }

    return (
        <span>Hello, World!</span>
    )
};

export default Example;
```

Using 'Show Call Hierarchy' on `changeValue` would return a list including `wrapperFunction` since it was called within that function. But using 'Show Call Hierarchy' on `setValue` returns `No results` in the References sidebar.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.